# Compare files in folders and delete non existent - part 2

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, batch-processing, file-management

After working with this line of code for years, it suddenly gives errors in Windows PowerShell:

```
for %F in ("D:\photos\2019\RAW\*.CR2") do @if not exist "D:\photos\2019\%~nF.jpg" echo del "%F"
```

The error:

```
At line:1 char:4
+ for %F in ("D:\photos\2019\RAW ...
+    ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
```

I've tried everything from single and double quotes and even `%%F` doesn't seem to work.

PS: this is a follow up from this one. I will add the solution there as well when this one is fixed.
[Windows: compare files in folders and delete non existent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970428/windows-compare-files-in-folders-and-delete-non-existent)

Comment: It'll always have given errors in PowerShell, as it's batch syntax. Why are you running this in PowerShell?

Comment: because it worked really well, actually.

Comment: Are you sure you're not high or otherwise confused? `for %F in (...)` is batch syntax, not PowerShell syntax. The latter looks like `for (init; cond; loop) ...`. Are you sure you didn't use to execute said command in a Command Prompt window instead of a PowerShell window?

Comment: It's clearly not possible that the code you posted has ever worked in PowerShell. The code is batch/CMD and you probably have been running it in the Windows Command Prompt before.

Comment: If you want to do this with Powershell, I would suggest this: [Powershell command to delete all files that do not exist in other folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1246847/powershell-command-to-delete-all-files-that-do-not-exist-in-other-folder)

Comment: Have you tried running this in cmd instead?